# Por qué el texto de mi aplicación no coincide con la previsualización de android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

El mensaje predeterminado `This is home fragment` siempre se muestra en el launcher aunque tenga un mensaje totalmente diferente en el TextView, por mas que lo modifique y cambie el aspecto el mensaje sigue siendo el mismo y ya no se que hacer, en internet no hay una respuesta a mi problema, asi que decidi recurrir aqui.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TxTBienvenida"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:background="#2B1E42"
    android:backgroundTint="#673AB7"
    android:contentDescription="@string/menu_home"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
    android:text="@string/menu_home"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.227"
    tools:text="Hola, y bienvenido a la App de registros de Call of Duty: Mobile!"
    tools:visibility="visible" />
```

Comment: Edit: Es un proyecto para una clase.

Answer (score 0):

Eso es porque estás escribiendo el texto en el atributo `tools:text` que solamente sirve para previsualizarlo en android studio. El valor real es el que está en el atributo `android:text` que actualmente es `@string/menu_home`. La solución es ir al archivo `res/values/strings.xml` y cambiar el valor de `menu_home` o bien agregar una nueva entrada y referenciarla en el atributo `android:text` del textView. También se puede harcodear el texto en vez de agregarlo en el archivo strings pero esto es una mala práctica y android studio te mostrará una advertencia.

**strings.xml**

```
<resources>
    ...
    <string name="menu_home">Hola, y bienvenido a la App de registros de Call of Duty: Mobile!</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Opción 1.** Elimina la linea en tu  **TextView**:

```
tools:text="Hola, y bienvenido a la App de registros de Call of Duty: Mobile!"
```

Modifica la siguiente linea. Pon tu texto aquí

```
android:text="@string/menu_home"
```

Queda así

```
    android:text="Hola, y bienvenido a la App de registros de Call of Duty: Mobile!"
```

**Opción 2**.. Modificar el valor en `res/values/string.xml`

Modifica el valor en

```
<string name="menu_home">This is Home Fragment</string>
```

Esta segunda opción es la mejor práctica, si algún día piensas traducir tu aplicación a otros idiomas